# PHP search multiple keywords in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Hi I've been trying to create a program like a search engine. So here's what I've got so far:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW5DU.jpg

I need to choose a symptoms on the select option then add it.
Those options that I added will begin to search on each rows on my Mysql Database. I need to output each matching keywords that I added.
It's a real pain, so I wanna know how you will solve this.

Here's my code:

```
$x = 0;
for($x; $x < 10;$x++) {

  $selx = "SELECT * FROM sicks WHERE tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a0']}%' AND id = $x ";
  $sel1 = mysqli_query($connect,$selx);

  $selx = "SELECT * FROM sicks WHERE tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a1']}%' AND id = $x ";
  $sel2 = mysqli_query($connect,$selx);

  $selx = "SELECT * FROM sicks WHERE tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a2']}%' AND id = $x ";
  $sel3 = mysqli_query($connect,$selx);

  $selx = "SELECT * FROM sicks WHERE tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a3']}%' AND id = $x ";
  $sel4 = mysqli_query($connect,$selx);

  $selx = "SELECT * FROM sicks WHERE tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a4']}%' AND id = $x ";
  $sel5 = mysqli_query($connect,$selx);

  $selx = "SELECT * FROM sicks WHERE tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a5']}%' AND id = $x ";
  $sel6 = mysqli_query($connect,$selx);

  $selx = "SELECT * FROM sicks WHERE tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a6']}%' AND id = $x ";
  $sel7 = mysqli_query($connect,$selx);

  $selx = "SELECT * FROM sicks WHERE tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a7']}%' AND id = $x ";
  $sel8 = mysqli_query($connect,$selx);

  $selx = "SELECT * FROM sicks WHERE tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a8']}%' AND id = $x ";
  $sel9 = mysqli_query($connect,$selx);

  $selx = "SELECT * FROM sicks WHERE tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a9']}%' AND id = $x ";
  $sel10 = mysqli_query($connect,$selx);

  $c1 = mysqli_num_rows($sel1);
  $c2 = mysqli_num_rows($sel2);
  $c3 = mysqli_num_rows($sel3);
  $c4 = mysqli_num_rows($sel4);
  $c5 = mysqli_num_rows($sel5);
  $c6 = mysqli_num_rows($sel6);
  $c7 = mysqli_num_rows($sel7);
  $c8 = mysqli_num_rows($sel8);
  $c9 = mysqli_num_rows($sel9);
  $c10 = mysqli_num_rows($sel10);

  $q2 = mysqli_query($sel2);
  $q3 = mysqli_query($sel3);
  $q4 = mysqli_query($sel4);
  $q5 = mysqli_query($sel5);
  $q6 = mysqli_query($sel6);
  $q7 = mysqli_query($sel7);
  $q8 = mysqli_query($sel8);
  $q9 = mysqli_query($sel9);
  $q10 = mysqli_query($sel10);
  $q1 = mysqli_query($sel1);

  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($q2);
  $_SESSION['news'] = $row['tags'];

  $every = $c1 + $c2 + $c3 + $c4 + $c5 + $c6 + $c7 + $c8 + $c9 ;

  echo $every;
}
```

The `{$_POST['a0']}`, `{$_POST['a1']}`, ... are the keywords came from the select option.

My JavaScript:

```
$('.sendit').click(function() {
  a0 = $('.a0').val();
  a1 = $('.a1').val();
  a2 = $('.a2').val();
  a3 = $('.a3').val();
  a4 = $('.a4').val();
  a5 = $('.a5').val();
  a6 = $('.a6').val();
  a7 = $('.a7').val();
  a8 = $('.a8').val();
  a9 = $('.a9').val();
  a10 = $('.a10').val();

  $.ajax({
    url:"function.php?sendit=true",
    type:"post",
    data:{a0:a0,
    a1:a1,
    a2:a2,
    a3:a3,
    a4:a4,
    a5:a5,
    a6:a6,
    a7:a7,
    a8:a8,
    a9:a9,
    a10:a10},
    success:function(data) {
      $('.texta').html(data);
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know why you’re calling `mysqli_query` two times, maybe it’s the context of your code.

I suggest you to **always** make the SQL server to these jobs. The interfacing language (especially php) may not exactly be as efficient as the SQL server.

My advice is to use the `OR` operator in the `WHERE` clause, so you’ll send only one query.

```
$selx = "SELECT * FROM sicks WHERE
(tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a0']}%' OR 
tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a1']}%' OR 
tags LIKE '%{$_POST['a2']}%' OR 
) AND id = $x";
```

**Note:** this code is SQL injectable. I suggest you to use `str_replace` on your `$_POST` values:

```
$_POST['a0'] = str_replace("'", "'", $_POST['a0']);
```

This will double all the single quotes, which are already used to delimit the strings.

About the [SQL injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thank you very much :) But what I want is to count all the matching tags so I can output the most match data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by in one query by stringing together the individual LIKEs with ORs

```
SELECT * FROM sicks
WHERE tags LIKE '%$_POST['a0']}%'
OR tags LIKE '%$_POST['a1']}%'
OR tags LIKE '%$_POST['a2']}%'
OR tags LIKE '%$_POST['a3']}%'
and so on...
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) But what I want is to count all the matching tags so I can output the most match data.